# Video (mp4) loading optimization for small web project

Tags: performance, video, nuxt.js, mp4, cdn

I'm currently developing my portfolio website using Nuxt3 in the frontend and Netlify for hosting. The site contains a fair amount of videos and although most mp4 files are not excessively large in size (1.2 - 1.4mb), requesting them directly from my server has taken a strain on the loading times of my site.

Aside from lazy-loading and compressing, what further steps could I take to optimize the loading speed of my videos? I am aware of CDNs such as Amazon Cloudfront and Cloudinary, but uncertain as to which would be most suitable for a small portfolio project.

Since this is quite a general question, any pointers to other techniques and best practices are much appreciated. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like images, video can have a billion things you can optimize and fine tune.

If it's a small portfolio project, just use Cloudinary. It will be super simple, highly optimized for you, will probably fall under a free tier and won't need reading a 400 pages book on how to work with various codes, containers, buffering etc etc...